# How many integers exist after the first string in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I'm learning to work with python and I'm having trouble working with a list of tuples. I'm trying to count the number of integers in each tuple after the name of each one.
ex. [('bagels',4,3,2,1), ('pies',6,5,4,2), ('cakes',12,11,10,0)]

My goal is to be able to save the names of each tuple then count the number of integers after them. I need the number of integers because I have to take into account multiple people wanting treats.

My end goal would be something like. ex. cakes:12 pies:6 if i printed the 2 highest valued treats. What should I do to skip over the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *dict comprehension*:

```
r = {v[0] : max(v[1:] for v in data}

print(r)
{'bagels': 4, 'cakes': 12, 'pies': 6}
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
r = {} # declare a dict
for v in data:
    i = v[0]        # find the item name
    j = max(v[1:])  # find the max of all integers following the item

    r[i] = j     # add an entry into the dictionary
```

**Details**

- A dict comprehension is a concise way of representing a `for` loop in python.
- `v[0]` retrieves the 0<sup>th</sup> element, and is assigned the key
- `max(v[1:]) finds the max of the integers following the item

At the end, if you want to display the result `r`, you can iterate over the it:

```
for k, v in r.items():
    print('{}:{}'.format(k, v))

cakes:12
bagels:4
pies:6
```

Note here, that dictionaries are *not ordered*, so you are not likely to print results in the same order as you input entries. In this case, you could consider using a `list`:

```
r = ['{}:{}'.format(v[0], max(v[1:])) for v in data]

print(r)
['bagels:4', 'pies:6', 'cakes:12']
```

Printing follows in a similar fashion. Call `sorted` with `reversed=True` if you want to print values from highest to lowest.

```
for i in sorted(r, reverse=True):
    print(i)

cakes:12
pies:6
bagels:4
```

Comment: I'm confused though how this works with each separate tuple

Comment: @Darkhail You iterate over each tuple, extract the 0'th element, find the size, and repeat.

Comment: So how am I iterating over each tuple?

Comment: @Darkhail Please re-read my answer again... I've modified it to return you the max value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary:

```
s= [('bagels',4,3,2,1), ('pies',6,5,4,2), ('cakes',12,11,10,0)]
data = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in s}
```

To find the highest value treats:

```
highest_val = 2
final_treats = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:max(x[-1]))[-highest_val:]
```

Output:

```
[('pies', (6, 5, 4, 2)), ('cakes', (12, 11, 10, 0))]
```

Comment: OP wants `len(i[1:])`, not `i[1:]`, see my answer.